# Mod_rewrite rule when query string paramter value not equal to set value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL:

```
domain.com?x=1&y=2&z=3
```

I have been trying to create a rule for when x does not equal 1 then x is set to 1

So for example: `domain.com?x=7&y=2&z=3` would rewrite to `domain.com?x=1&y=2&z=3`

That is x (if present) should always = 1 and all other parameters and values should remain the same.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I suppose the best way would be to do this in the script handling the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code (your htaccess has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^x=([^&]*)(.*)$
RewriteCond %1 !=1
RewriteRule . /?x=1%2 [R=301,L]
```